# Regex for hyphenated words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have hyphen separated words in paragraphs that I'm trying to extract.

I've tried following regex `\w+-\w`, however this is not working as expected.

Here's the complete code written in JavaScript.

```
var string = "time to eval-u-ate";
var result = string.match(/\w+-\w/g); // ["eval-u"]
```

This returns the string `eval-u`. I want the result to be `eval-u-ate`. How can I modify the regex to match complete hyphenated words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use following regex

```
((?:\w+-)+\w+)
```

1. `(?:\w+-)+`: Matches one or more alphanumeric characters including underscore symbol followed by a hyphen. `(?:` will make it not add in captured group
2. `\w+`: Matches one or more alphanumeric characters including underscore symbol
3. `()`: Capturing group. The matches can be accessed by using `$n` where `n` is the capturing group number. `$1` in this case as it is first capturing group.
4. `g`: Use global flag to get all possible matches

**Demo**

```js
var string = "time to eval-u-ate Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A sed, illum veritatis aut recusandae tempora possimus iure totam distinctio necessitatibus temporibus labore-numquam-dignissimos, officiis velit error-dolores nostrum ipsam.";
var matches = string.match(/((?:\w+-)+\w+)/g);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(matches, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jN7iT1/2)